# googlesheets R authentication error

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I used to have the googlesheets package in R pulling data off my drive account just fine, but recently when I start up I can't access the data. I've tried using  the gs_auth(new_user=TRUE) to reset, but when I get taken to the web browser, I accept that I'm giving permission to access google, but then I get an error message saying the webpage is not available with the message "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET the connection to localhost was interrupted". I recently tried to use the boxR package to access data stored on box.com, did I change some setting that now is preventing  googlesheets from working? If so, is there a specific way to fix it, or is a system restore to an earlier date the cleanest solution to getting google sheets to authenticate properly?

Comment: How long ago was it working? The Sheets api changed last year and only "old" sheets could still be accessed. Recently I noticed that the have been forcibly converting old format sheets to new sheets. You could see if this script helps https://github.com/elinw/ShinyGoogleSheets/blob/nodata/scripts/readGoogleSheet.R  if it does I will make it an answer.

Comment: I had it working two weeks ago. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstalling and reinstalling the httr and googlsheets packages does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a more trivial reason:
You must "publish" every google sheet "as web page" (you can select the entire worksheet or a particular sheet).
After that, you must "share" the sheet.
Hope that helps!